# Jaxb custom element from two fields of an object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way with jaxb to create a custom element from two fields from an object?
Here's an example of what I have and what I want.  I realize I could extract the fields into a seperate annotated class, but I'm curious of theres a way to do something similar to this.

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Foo {
   public String bar
   public String baz
}
```

Expected output xml:

```
<foo>
  <customElement bar="barValue">bazValue</customElement>
</foo>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class for foo

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Foo {

   private customElement CustomElement;

   public CustomElement getCustomElement(){
       return customElement;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setCustomElement(CustomElement customElement){
       this.customElement = customElement;
   }
}
```

class for custom element

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomElement {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String bar;

    @XmlValue
    private String baz

    // set getters and setters
}
```

Comment: @jammin if the above solution works, please upvote :-) Thanks!